# SIGABRT handler. Do some cleanup before crash

Tags: linux, unix, ipc, sigabrt

I have added a sighandler for `SIGABRT` signal.

The default behavior of `abort()` is to generate a core-dump.

I would like to do the same in signal handler but before crashing, execute cleanup code.

I have tried as below and I know that below piece of code is not going to work.

```
static void
proc_sigabort_handler (int signo UNUSED)
{
    /* cleanup */
    abort(); /* This is to coredump */
}

signal(SIGABRT, proc_sigabort_handler);
```

Problem:
`abort()` call in sighandler raises `SIGABRT` signal and end up in same sighandler function and this goes on.

Is there any syscall similar to `abort()` to generate a core-dump?

## Edit after some replies:

```
user@srv1 ~/linux>  uname -a

Linux srv1 2.4.21-63.ELsmp #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:15:46 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Linux abort(3) man Page:

> If the SIGABRT signal is ignored, or caught by a handler that returns,
>   the abort() function will still terminate the process. It does this by
>   restoring the default disposition for SIGABRT and then raising the
>   signal for a second time.

Ex:

```
void mysigabort()
{
    printf("I caught the SIGABRT signal!\n");/* I know that printf should be avoided */
    return;    
} 

int main()
{
    signal(SIGABRT, mysigabort);

    while(1);  /* infinite loop */

    exit(0);
}
```

Produces:

```
user@srv1 ~/linux>  ./a.out

I caught the SIGABRT signal!

<cursor>


user@srv1 ~/linux>  kill -6 25208
```

No cores found. Even process is not terminated.

If there is no user-defined signal handler, core is generated.

Comment: I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that it is a good idea to `fflush(stdout);` after that print in your `SIGABRT` handler to ensure the statement is printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may restore the default SIGABRT behavior before catching it the second time :

```
void mysigabort(int signum)
{
    // whatever you want
    signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    kill(getpid(), signum); // or abort() ?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `abort` man-page on Linux:

> If the SIGABRT signal is ignored, or caught by a handler  that  returns,  the  abort()
>   function will still terminate the process.  It does this by restoring the default dis‐
>   position for SIGABRT and then raising the signal for a second time.

OP [Ram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1635197/ram) pointed out that this is Linux-specific, but there, you can simply return from your signal handler - there is no need to call `abort()` a second time. libc's `abort()` will take care of the rest.

Comment: I have tried the same.
It does not seem to be doing that in BSD.

Comment: Linux man page:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/abort

BSD man page:
http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=abort&sektion=3

Comment: Even if SIGABRT is raised for the second time, we do endup in same sighandler function.

Comment: I quickly tested it, second time SIGABRT did not enter into signal-handler but still there is no crash generated and pid of proc is still the same.

Comment: Interesting. The Linux manpage doesn't mention that this is Linux specific. I've added that, thanks! As I've said, it's the `abort()` implementation which takes care of calling the handler a second time. In your test case, you've sent the SIGABRT signal by other means. Try calling `abort()` in place of your infinite `while` loop. (It's save to assume that a library function would use the libc `abort()`.) Of course, this does not solve the platform dependance problem.

Comment: Try calling abort() in place of your infinite while loop.

Yes this works, but that is not what I want to do.

In case if process gets SIBABRT (signal 6) from external sources,
in program sigabrt handler, I would like to clean up few things and then abort (core-dump).

adding abort() in main function is not going to solve what I am looking for.

I have added abort() in mysigabort() function, and sent kill -6 <pid> to process. But this one resulted in multiple printfs and finally core. I don't want this too. After printf() in sighandler, just generate core-dump.

Comment: External sources will in almost all cases use `abort()` rather than just sending the signal, that's what I wanted to say. (If you only want to solve your problem, you could also call `signal(SIGABRT, SIG_DFL)` before calling `abort()` from the signal handler. But I don't know how portable that is either..)

Comment: Yes, it works after resetting handler to default.
signal(SIGABRT, SIG_DFL); then abort();
This looks like a workaround.
It does not seem to be behaving as man page says.
According to man page, SIGABRT should have terminated and generated core-dump even if there is a user-defined sigabrt handler.
Anyways, this is resolved now. Thanks.